# "Unselect" event for MenuItem

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to implement a 'preview' scenario when the user hover a menu item.

For example, lets say a program has a context-menu with 'Set Color' sub-menu.
The sub-menu pop a list of color to choose from.
Now, when the mouse cursor is over a specific color, I want it to change a label of "Selected color".
And when the mouse cursor leave the selected color menu-item, I want to label to restore its original text.

The following code demonstrate changing the label when menu-item selected - mouse is over.

```
    private void Init()
    {
        var mnuContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        this.ContextMenu = mnuContextMenu;

        var smthingElseMenu = new MenuItem("Do something else");
        var setColorMenu = new MenuItem("Set Color");

        var colorBlue = new MenuItem("Blue");
        var colorRed = new MenuItem("Red");
        var colorGreen = new MenuItem("Green");

        mnuContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(smthingElseMenu);
        mnuContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(setColorMenu);
        setColorMenu.MenuItems.Add(colorBlue);
        setColorMenu.MenuItems.Add(colorRed);
        setColorMenu.MenuItems.Add(colorGreen);

        colorBlue.Select += ColorSelect;
        colorRed.Select += ColorSelect;
        colorGreen.Select += ColorSelect;
    }

    void ColorSelect(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblSelectedColor.Text = ((MenuItem) sender).Text;
    }
```

But I couldn't find a way to make the label text restore when the mouse cursor leave the menu-item.
Any ideas how can I implement some kind of 'Unselect'/'MouseLeave' event for MenuItem?

Comment: Very hard to imagine how this could be useful, you'll never have a selected color when the context menu closes.  Do consider using the ContextMenuStrip class instead.  The ToolSTripMenuItem class has a MouseLeave event.  And a Checked property, probably what you really want.

Comment: This is useful if I only want to preview on mouse "Hover". I'll have the selected color set when the user actually _click_ on that menuitem.  The ContextMenuStrip and ToolSTripMenuItem are the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, makes sense.  In which case the ContextMenu.Closed event is good enough to restore the previous selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "un-select" event for MenuItems, unfortunately.

I would just catch the [Collapse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.collapse%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event of your context menu, and reset your label there.  This would have the added benefit that if your user hovers over the "Red" option, then hovers off the context menu, the label should stay red until the context menu closes.

```
mnuContextMenu.Collapse += (s, e) => lblSelectedColor.Text = "None";
```

If you really need it to reset the label when your mouse leave the context menu, then you could catch the `MouseEnter` event of the Panel (or whatever) you have that surrounds the ContextMenu.

```
MyPanel.MouseEnter += (s, e) => lblSelectedColor.Text = "None";
```

**EDIT** Do consider using the ContextMenuStrip class instead. The ToolSTripMenuItem class has a MouseLeave event. And a Checked property, probably what you really want.

Comment: I need the label to change when the cursor is on the menu-item, and return to it's original state when the cursor leaves the menu-item.

Comment: @avir - why do you say that?  It's a public event you can subscribe to.

Comment: The collapse event won't help in this case, because I need the label to restore even if the menu still visible and the cursor is not on the menu-item.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just save the old MenuItem ref.

```
private MenuItem _oldMenuItem;

void ColorSelect(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(_oldMenuItem != null) _oldMenuItem.Text = someText;
        _oldMenuItem = sender as MenuItem;

        lblSelectedColor.Text = ((MenuItem) sender).Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events to handle everything. First is raised when when the mouse pointer enters the bounds of this element. And second mouse pointer leaves the bounds - at this point you restore default label text.

**EDIT** like Hans pointed in comment use ContextMenuStrip and ToolStripMenuItems and youll have those events.

Comment: How do i use it for MenuItem class? it seems that these events doesn't exists.

Comment: Both methods do exist in the MenuItem class

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use:

```
    private void colorBlue_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // use color blue
    }

    private void colorBlue_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // use old color
    }
```